# ASP.NET MVC Using Modal popup with button onclick inside a jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently i'm doing a page which contains a table which contains some data. However, I want to put a bootstrap modal to show a message content inside the body of the popup. But I don't know how to process with the button because when i'm clicking on every buttons inside the table it shows me the same message content and it should not. Each rows, I mean most of them should not have the same message content.

```
@model Savoye.BridgeServices.Models.MessageModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Administration";
}

@{
    var data = ViewBag.Channels;
    var msg = ViewBag.Msg;
}

<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.datatables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <br />
    <form asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="AdminMessageManagement">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select name="getChannelValue">
                    <option value="">Select Channel</option>
                    @foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        <option value="@item">@item</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="getMessageKeyValue" placeholder="Message Key" />
                <select name="getIsDelivered">
                    <option value="">Is Delivered ?</option>
                    <option value=true>True</option>
                    <option value=false>False</option>
                </select>
                <input type="date" id="start" name="getDateFrom" value="@null" />
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
                <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AdminTest", "Administration")'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<br />

<table id="dataTable_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Source Channel</th>
            <th>Message Key</th>
            <th>IsDelivered ?</th>
            <th>Target Channel</th>
            <th>Send Date</th>
            <th>Reception Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in msg)
        {
            @foreach (var target in item.Targets)
            {
                <tr>  
                    <td class="details-control"><i class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bootstrapmodal" id="iconAdd" style="font-size:22px"></i></td>
                    <td>@item.SourceChannel</td>
                    <td>@item.MessageKey</td>
                    <td>@target.IsDelivered</td>
                    <td>@target.Channel</td>
                    <td>@item.Date</td>
                    <td>@target.DateDelivered</td>
                </tr>             
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@foreach (var item in msg)
{
    <div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Message :</div>
                <div class="modal-body">@item.Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    @section Scripts{
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dataTable_id').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverside": true,
                    "filter": false,
                    "paging": true
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

The popup is there :

```
@foreach (var item in msg)
{
    <div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Message :</div>
                <div class="modal-body">@item.Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and I would like that this button :

```
<td class="details-control"><i class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bootstrapmodal" id="iconAdd" style="font-size:22px"></i></td>
```

show me the Message content of each row in the table.
I retrieved well, every data I need in the data except data in the popup. In the popup this is the same message content shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you make your rows replace the double foreach with this one:

```
@foreach (var item in msg)
{
    <div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal-@item">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Message :</div>
                <div class="modal-body">@item.Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var target in item.Targets)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="details-control"><i class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bootstrapmodal-@item" id="iconAdd" style="font-size:22px"></i></td>
            <td>@item.SourceChannel</td>
            <td>@item.MessageKey</td>
            <td>@target.IsDelivered</td>
            <td>@target.Channel</td>
            <td>@item.Date</td>
            <td>@target.DateDelivered</td>
        </tr>
    }

}
```

and delete the foreach below the table where you make the modals, cause it is included in the double foreach now. This should work.

Comment: The issue is that I can't use div inside <tr> and <tbody> so i'm not able what you did, or you maybe have another option

Comment: Well you can because it is not visible, but anyways, what else you can try is with your code, just replace in your popup: bootstrapmodal with bootstrapmodal-@item and in your table data-target=".bootstrapmodal" with data-target=".bootstrapmodal-@item". The problem is just the naming, you keep on making modals with the same name so bootstrap doesn't know which one to open.

Comment: That's a good idea, but with those rename when i'm clicking on button, it's not working anymore. Do you think i should rename bootstrapmodal-@item.Content ?

Comment: Yes with that changement, when I click on the button, the popup doesn't show

Comment: Did you change both to bootstrapmodal-@item.Content ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, I would do something stupid like this: https://pastebin.com/Dwa2S6hq

Comment: Ok the counter make it works, thanks a lot @Costa

Comment: I changed both to  to bootstrapmodal-@item.Content and it does not work. But the last one works even if it's not beautiful but thanks :p